# newtype with RankNTypes

Tags: haskell, higher-rank-types, newtype

If I want to declare a `newtype` such that type type of the value is constrained to have an instance for a type-class, it seems like I can do that with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype ShowBox = ShowBox (forall a. Show a => a)
```

GHC compiles that just fine, but when I try and actually use `ShowBox` with

```
ShowBox "hello"
```

I get a compiler error

```
<interactive>:1:18:
    Could not deduce (a ~ [Char])
    from the context (Show a)
      bound by a type expected by the context: Show a => a
      at <interactive>:1:10-24
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          a type expected by the context: Show a => a at <interactive>:1:10
    In the first argument of `ShowBox', namely `"hello"'
    In the expression: ShowBox "hello"
    In an equation for `a': a = ShowBox "hello"
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Does this quantification mean what you think it means? I'm really not sure, myself. I'm thinking it _may_ mean that `ShowBox` can only be applied to values that are precisely of type `Show a => a`. I am quite interested to see what is the answer to this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're promising the compiler that the value you put inside a `ShowBox` will have the type `forall a. Show a => a`. There's only one possible value with that type, and it's `_|_`. I think you probably want an existential type, which looks rather similar, but means something very different.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data ShowBox = forall a. Show a => ShowBox a
```

This must be done with `data`, rather than `newtype`. Pattern-matching on the constructor is what brings the Show instance into scope, in this case. Since `newtype`s have no run-time representation, they have no place to store the polymorphic witness the existential quantification implies.

Comment: That is to say: the values that go in @user1279710's `ShowBox` have to be able to be *any* instance of `Show`, but he tried to put one *particular* instance of `Show` in. (pause for subject change) The only value of type `forall a. Show a => a` is `_|_` in this case because the `Show` typeclass doesn't include any methods for constructing values of the instance type, only for consuming them.

Comment: It would be nice if the compiler gave warnings like "useless data declaration: `Show a => a`: can only be inhabited by `_|_`"

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I was hoping there was some way to do this without boxing, but I see that it isn't really possible.  Thanks.

Comment: @purefn The boxing is important. In the case of existential types with class limitations, the boxing actually stores the class dictionary at runtime. That's what's needed to actually use the class, rather than just be a limitation at construction time.

Comment: Keep in mind that this `ShowBox` is essentaily the same as `String`.  In many cases existential types can be reduced to simpler, concrete types; look for those opportunities, they could simplify your codebase.

Answer (score 7):

Well, your `Show` constructor has this type:

```
Show :: (forall a. Show a => a) -> ShowBox
```

You're trying to apply this function to type `[Char]`, which is not of type `forall a. Show a => a`, because the `a` is a "Skolem variable" that only be unified with another type under very strict rules (which others will be able to explain better than I can).

Are you sure the following is not what you want (modulo `data` vs. `newtype`)?  Why did you scope the `forall` inside the constructor?

```
-- Show :: Show a => a -> ShowBox
data ShowBox = forall a. Show a => Show a
```